# Livewire wire:loading not work in dynamically showing sections

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-blade

I'm using Laravel 9.

```
@if ($license_id)
  <x-jet-button wire:click="update_license">
     <x-spinner wire:loading wire:target="update_license" />
     Update
  </x-jet-button>
@else
   <x-jet-button wire:click="add_license">
      <x-spinner wire:loading wire:target="add_license" />
      Add
   </x-jet-button>
@endif
```

Here both update_license & add_license work and by default Add button is showing and the spinner is working. (Spinner is just a component with tailwind spinner class).

When the license_id is set by a click event, the Update button and the license_update function are working but Spinner is not showing.

Can anyone help me with this?